# Using jcarousel, how can I get the image alt to display in an external div#caption

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcarousel

I am using: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Configuration

And I am implementing this locally to prove functionality before I load it into a site.  My current setup is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {

jQuery('#mycarousel-next').bind('click', function() {
    carousel.next();
    return false;
});

jQuery('#mycarousel-prev').bind('click', function() {
    carousel.prev();
    return false;
});
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#mycarousel").jcarousel({
    scroll: 1,
    visible: 1.1,   
    initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
    buttonNextHTML: null,
    buttonPrevHTML: null,
    itemLoadCallback: trigger
});
});
function trigger(carousel, state)
{
$("#counter").html(carousel.first);  
}
</script>
<div id="clip">

<ul id="mycarousel">
    <li><img src="images/bda_1.jpg" alt="Alt Tag 1" width="638" height="358"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/bda_2.jpg" alt="Alt Tag 2" width="638" height="358" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/bda_3.jpg" alt="Alt Tag 3" width="638" height="358" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/bda_1.jpg" width="638" height="358" /></li>
</ul>

</div>
 <a href="#" id="mycarousel-prev">&laquo; Prev</a>
 <a href="#" id="mycarousel-next">&laquo; NEXT</a>

<div id="counter"></div>

<div id="caption"></div>
```

I know I can use a callback but my js/jquery is to beginner to get it done.  I simply want to pull the alt tag out and display it in the div#caption

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the jcarousel main loop (which I don't see in your code) you'd so this:

```
$('#caption').html($('mycarousel').find('img').eq(COUNTER).attr('alt'))
```

Where the value of COUNTER comes fom you'll have to find in the script. If there's a callback for this function you could put it there.

Comment: By main loop do you mean where I setup mycarousel?

Comment: So I assume (from trying) that I can't put this into my "function trigger"... and use carousel.first to identify the specific slide its on because it didn't work... any thing else you can point me towards?